# How to call AngularJS Service code from android webview?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webview

I'm trying to call AngularJS service from android webview component without success...
Do you have any idea how can I do this ?

This is the java script code I'm trying to call:

```
view.loadUrl("javascript:$rootScope.myService.hello()");
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have [disabled debug data](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production#!) then each element in your app has a `scope()` function you can call to get back the scope for that element. It also has an `injector()` function you can use to get back the injector instance for your app. So try this:

```
javascript:angular.element('[ng-app]').injector().get('myService').hello()
```

It would probably be better to expose just the function that you need access to on the window though.

So then you would need to do something like this:

```
angular.module('myApp').service('myService', function(yourDependencies..., $window) {
  //Your code 

  $window.hello = this.hello;
});
```

Then your Android code becomes this:

```
view.loadUrl("javascript:hello()");
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you.

This worked for me : 
view.loadUrl("javascript:hello()");

Comment: could you explain more about where the code `angular.module('myApp').service('myService', function(yourDependencies..., $window) {
  //Your code 

  $window.hello = this.hello;
});`  should be added in? I am newer of angularJS